# How to align the text file which is created by Stream writer in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, text-files, streamwriter

I use the following code for read the data from sql server 2005 and add that data into list.Then I use to create a text file with that list.It was work fine.

```
    String con1 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

     try
            {
                List<string> list = new List<string>();

                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(con1))
                {
                    con.Open();

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM test", con))
                    {
                        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            string name = reader.GetString(0);
                            string dept = reader.GetString(1);
                            list.Add(name);
                            list.Add(dept);
                        }
                        StreamWriter SW;
                        SW = File.CreateText("d:\\test.txt");

                        foreach (string Txt in list)
                        {
                            SW.WriteLine(Txt);
                        }


                        SW.Close();
                    }
                }
```

my problem is alignment **if i create the text file the record will show line by line**.here aaaa,cccc are name.bbbb,dddd are Dept.But it show like,

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
dddd
```

But **I need  name,dept separtely like as a table**

```
aaaa       bbbb
cccc       dddd
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Change this lines

```
list.Add(name);
list.Add(dept);
```

to

```
list.Add(name + "\t" + dept);
```

Comment: They will probably _not_ line up neatly.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i += 2)
{
   SW.Write(list[i]);
   SW.Write("\t");
   SW.WriteLine(list[i+1]);
}
```

Comment: If your list though has an odd number of elements, this will throw an unhanded error. With how elements are being added to the list, this shouldn't happen, but I would probably put a check in anyways.

Comment: @userx, You're right in a general case, but I prefer not to put a code that won't be used.